# pydev django template formatting

Tags: django, django-templates, pydev

I'm used to auto-format my sources with eclipse. To do so I select all text and press Ctrl+Shift+F.
But In the case of django template files as for example

```
{% extends "base.html" %} 
{% load staticfiles %} 
{% block content %}
<div class="row">
...
```

by Ctrl+Shift+F I would end up with

```
{% extends "prototipo/base.html" %} {% load staticfiles %} {% block
content %}
<div class="row">
```

which leads to a TemplateSyntaxError.
Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

In the meanwhile I developed this script, positioned in the tamplates dir. I run it after a Ctrl+Shift+F.

```
import re
import os

def fix_template(filename):
    with open(filename,'r+') as f:
        content=f.read()
        for s in re.findall('(\{%((?!%}).)*\n.*%})',content):
            faulty_string=s[0]
            non_faulty_string=faulty_string.replace('\n',' ')
            content=content.replace(faulty_string,non_faulty_string)
        f.seek(0)
        f.write(content)

basedir=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(basedir):
    for filename in filenames:
        if re.match('.*[.]html',filename) is not None:
            fix_template(os.path.join(dirpath,filename))
```

Answer (score 0):

Humm, that editor is from LiClipse (and not PyDev) right?

I think the problem there is that it's using the default HTML code-formatter, whereas it should use a django-templates aware code-formatter.

Please report that as an issue to LiClipse (https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/LiClipse) -- although note that the LiClipse way of doing things is delegating those actions to external libraries (so, HTML formatting works because it was available in an external library -- so, in this case, the option could either be disabling formatting or finding a library which implements it).